# Retain only records (IDs) in common between two data sets

Tags: sas

is there a way to remove from a data set the IDs (that are also replicated) not present in a second data set?

dataset1

> ```
> ID     Age
> ```
>
> 00001   34-50
> 00001   34-50
> 00002   30-50
> 00002   30-50
> 00002   30-50
> 00005   25-34
> 00005   25-34
> 00006   45-50
> ....    ....

dataset2

> ```
> ID     Sex
> ```
>
> 00001     F
> 00001     F
> 00002     F
> 00002     F
> 00002     F
> 00004     M
> 00004     M
> 00003     F
> ....    ....

Desired output

> ```
> ID     Sex
> ```
>
> 00001     F
> 00001     F
> 00002     F
> 00002     F
> 00002     F
> ....    ....

```
I tried (without success):
>      proc sql;
>      select*from dataset1
>      where ID in(select ID from dataset2),
>      quit;
```

Comment: Define "without success"?  Did it not run?  Did your actual code have the typos that are in the code you posted here?   Or did it run but not produce the output you expected?  Is the goal to produce a printout, like the posted code, or do you actually want to create a new dataset?  If the later you will need to change the SQL code to tell it what dataset to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data one;
input ID $ Age $;
datalines;
00001 34-50
00001 34-50
00002 30-50
00002 30-50
00002 30-50
00005 25-34
00005 25-34
00006 45-50
;

data two;
input ID $ Sex $;
datalines;
00001 F
00001 F
00002 F
00002 F
00002 F
00004 M
00004 M
00003 F
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select two.*
   from two
   where two.ID in (select ID from one)
   ;
quit;
```